# Combo box do not select Value from drop down

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJs to create a combobox.
Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('Form.FormTypeDialog', {
extend : 'Ext.Window',

id: 'formTypeDialog',

formId: null,

callbackFunction : null,

modal: true,

statics : {
    show : function(formId, callback) {
        Ext.create(Form.FormTypeDialog", {
            formId : formId,
            callbackFunction : callback
        }).show();
    }
},

constructor : function(config) {
    var me = this;

    Ext.apply(this, {
        buttons : [
            {
                text:"#{msgs.form_create_dialog_button_cancel}",
                cls : 'secondaryBtn',
                handler: function() {
                    me.close();
                }
            },
            {
                text:"#{msgs.form_create_dialog_button_next}",
                handler: function() {
                    // Get selected form type

                }
            }
        ]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

initComponent:function() {
    this.setTitle("#{msgs.form_create_dialog_title}");
    this.setHeight(175);
    this.setWidth(327);

    var formTypeStore = Mystore.Store.createRestStore({
        url : getRelativeUrl('/rest/form/formTypes'),
        root: 'objects',
        fields: ['name','value']
    });

    this.form = new Ext.form.Panel({
        style:'padding:15px;background-color:#fff' ,
        border:false,
        bodyBorder:false,
        items:[
            new Ext.form.Label({
                text: "#{msgs.form_create_dialog_select_type_label}",
                margin: "25 10 25 5"
            }),
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                id: 'createformTypeCombo',
                margin: "8 10 25 5",
                allowBlank: false,
                forceSelection: true,
                editable:false,
                store: formTypeStore,
                valueField: 'value',
                displayField: 'name',
                width: 260,
                emptyText: '#{msgs.form_create_dialog_select_type}'
            })
        ]
    });

    this.items = [
        this.form
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

I am creating this window on a xhtml page on a button click using :

```
Form.FormTypeDialog.show(null, showFormWindowCallBack);
```

It works fine and combo box is displayed and I can select value.

But if I open and close it 4 times, then in next show it shows the values but It do not allow me to select the last two value. I can only select first value.

[image]

Please suggest.

**Note:** I have tried copying and executing this code in forms of other pages of my application. But behavior is same in all cases.
This combobox is on a Ext.Window.

EDIT:
JSON RESPONSE FROM Rest:

> {"attributes":null,"complete":true,"count":3,"errors":null,"failure":false,"metaData":null,"objects":[{"name":"Application
>   Provisioning Policy Form","value":"Application"},{"name":"Role
>   Provisioning Policy Form","value":"Role"},{"name":"Workflow
>   Form","value":"Workflow"}],"requestID":null,"retry":false,"retryWait":0,"status":"success","success":true,"warnings":null}

Comment: in the failing scenario have you validated the actual response of the server side? Works well if you close and open 2 o3 times ?

Comment: You have to supply more information. What version of ExtJS do you use, how does the store cfg look and so on. Best would be a fiddle.sencha.com which reproduce the error.

Comment: We could do with additional information on this issue to be able to help,I have created a fiddle using the code you supplied but added my own data and have been unable to replicate the issue

[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fod)

Could you let us know which version of ExtJS you are using and whether you are seeing any errors in the console when this happens.

Comment: Just to be clinical, did you try the following -
 - Did you try different browsers?
 - If so, are you doing anything funky while selecting a value from the combo box? i.e. outside this initComponent function
 - Did you try having the store outside this initComponent function and setting it to **autoLoad**? (Not sure what's within that createRestStore. Even though it doesn't look like a loading issue, I don't know if Ext JS is doing any kind of weird caching with Window / Combo Boxes that would prevent you from choosing values. Really a long shot)
- Did you try adding a semi-colon to style?

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan No i am not doing any funky here. I just have next and close button inside a constructor defined in same class. But I have also tried putting them in initcomponents(), but it results in the same.

Comment: @Scriptable I am using Ext 4.1.0. I have tried my code in your Fiddle. But I am not able to reproduce it. I am loading data from the Java Rest API.

Comment: @Scriptable My combobox is on a Ext.Window. When I open and close window 5 times continuously without page refresh, this issue occurs.

Comment: Could you provide a sample JSON response that you get and create a fiddle? I'll have a play around with it today, it will be something simple but difficult to find. I'm surprised your not seeing errors in the console window though. If you can provide a replication of the issue I'll figure it out, I just can't replicate it

Comment: @Scriptable I have edited my answer with the JSON response. I am not getting any error on the console. If you see the image, there is some gap between combo box and the first item. I don't know why this is coming

Comment: Have you tried it without a window mate? would be good if you could post the code for the window loading and display, the issue could be with that rather than the combo itself.

Comment: @Scriptable I have updated the code. No  i have not tried it. I will try now.

Comment: This line is missing a double quote by the way, `statics : {
    show : function(formId, callback) {
        Ext.create(HEREForm.FormTypeDialog", {` I would also try this without using statics, try removing the statics and try just creating with `var win = Ext.create("Form.FormTypeDialog").show();`

Comment: Yeah I was doing the same way earlier. I updated code today only. same issue after removing static and creating window using the way you specified.

Comment: I've updated my old answer that I previously removed. This loads the window as many times as I like without any issues, I did get a lot of errors reported in Firebug though when loading your code which I've fixed in the below answer. Could you try that code and let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

I have re-created this code, I had some errors showing in Firefox using your code directly so I've changed some things.

Running the code below and calling `Ext.create("Form.FormTypeDialog", {}).show();` in the console window, then closing the window and repeating does not replicate this issue. Could you try using the code I have and see if you still have the same problem.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('Form.FormTypeDialog', {
            extend: 'Ext.Window',
            id: 'formTypeDialog',
            formId: null,
            callbackFunction: null,
            modal: true,

            constructor: function (config) {
                var me = this;

                Ext.apply(this, {
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "#{msgs.form_create_dialog_button_cancel}",
                            cls: 'secondaryBtn',
                            handler: function () {
                                me.close();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: "#{msgs.form_create_dialog_button_next}",
                            handler: function () {
                                // Get selected form type

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },

            initComponent: function () {
                this.setTitle("#{msgs.form_create_dialog_title}");
                this.setHeight(175);
                this.setWidth(327);

                var myData = [
                    ["Application Provisioning Policy Form", "Application"],
                    ["Role Provisioning Policy Form", "Role"],
                    ["Workflow Form", "Workflow"],
                ];

                var formTypeStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.ArrayStore", {
                    fields: [
                        'name',
                        'value'
                    ],
                    data: myData,
                    storeId: "myStore"
                });

                this.form = Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel", {
                    style: 'padding:15px;background-color:#fff',
                    border: false,
                    bodyBorder: false,
                    items: [
                        Ext.create("Ext.form.Label", {
                            text: "#{msgs.form_create_dialog_select_type_label}",
                            margin: "25 10 25 5"
                        }),
                        Ext.create("Ext.form.ComboBox", {
                            id: 'createformTypeCombo',
                            margin: "8 10 25 5",
                            allowBlank: false,
                            forceSelection: true,
                            editable: false,
                            store: formTypeStore,
                            valueField: 'value',
                            displayField: 'name',
                            width: 260,
                            emptyText: '#{msgs.form_create_dialog_select_type}'
                        })
                    ]
                });

                this.items = [
                    this.form
                ];

                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Click me',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            handler: function() {
                Ext.create("Form.FormTypeDialog", {}).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can also play around with this code using / forking from this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ftm)

Comment: This is more a comment, not a answer. Please add it as comment and delete this post

Comment: I have tried this. Basically you are using this Ext.create to create components. I might have to look on other sides also. It seems like some different problem to me.

Comment: I'm not sure statics is being used properly in this instance as you see in the docs here. [Ext.base.Statics](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-statics). Does it work fine for you when using Ext.create?

Comment: Even if I remove static, issue remains the same. Thanks for assisting me so far.

Comment: The only things I've changed from your code above is the store's data source and the removal of statics. and the issue does not present itself. What browser are you testing it in?, what size screen are you using? is there any other code affecting the window at all, positioning? z-indexing?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 and Mozilla Beta.. Size screen in 14'', but it occurs on laptop as well as desktop. I think I might need to check any other code on this page.

Comment: Yeah can you try running that code on its own and see if you still get the issue. Does that fiddle above run ok for you?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes it runs fine. I was trying to create a button on that fiddle and was trying to load window on click of that. But I am new to JavaScript.  That is my requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68282/discussion-between-code-fish-and-scriptable).

Comment: I've added a button to the code which will load the window

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your problem is.
I use remote combo follows:

```
Ext.define('ComboRemote', {
extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
xtype: 'ComboRemote',
emptyText: 'empty',
width: 75,
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
store: {
    model: 'ComboModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/serv/Res',
        extraParams: {
            query: ''
        },
        reader: {
            root: "result", type: 'json'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
},
queryMode: 'remote',
pageSize: false,
lastQuery: '',
minChars: 0});

Ext.define('ComboModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    'id',
    'name'
]});
```

I hope to help

Answer (score 1):

Try these possible solutions
1.   Make AutoLoad property for store as true.
2.   Add delay of some ms

Comment: Delay will wait your ajax call for desired milliseconds. This is used where store is getting time to populate.